# Error when calculating percent error in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have a neural network and I am trying to calculate the percent error.

```
for i in range(len(y_test_predicted)):
    difference = np.array(abs(y_test_predicted[i] - y_test_unscaled[i]))
    print("Difference: ",difference)
    error = np.array(difference/y_test_predicted[i])
    print("error: ",error)
    print("---------------")

av_error = np.mean(error)
av_per_error = av_error * 100
```

I have predicted values and actual values. I take the absolute value of their difference and divide by the predicted value. However the error array  is only a single value. It gets over written each time the loop iterates. I tried using

```
    error[i] = np.array(difference/y_test_predicted[i])
```

But it throws an error saying that it is out of bounds. I also tried hard coding the problem to avoid using array's by just having a running sum of all the error values but it keeps returning NaN for some reason.

Comment: Why not use `error.append`? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html

Comment: yes I think that could work. I am still a little new to python and not quite aware of such functions. I did realize I was getting NaN because some of the data that I was using to test the model had NaN so I removed that and the function worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `y_test_predicted` and `y_test_unscaled` are numpy arrays, you can use numpy's vectorised operators and avoid the for loop entirely, like so:

```
difference = np.abs(y_test_predicted - y_test_unscaled)
error = difference / y_test_predicted
av_error = np.mean(error)
```

For instance:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y_test_unscaled = np.array([0.11, 0.63, 0.44, 0.54, 0.65])
>>> y_test_predicted = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7])
>>> difference = np.abs(y_test_predicted - y_test_unscaled)
>>> error = difference / y_test_predicted
>>> av_error = np.mean(error)
>>> av_error
0.19561904761904764
```

If you're hellbent on using a loop, then the error you're getting is probably because `error` is the wrong shape (though I can't tell that for sure as it's not included in your question). Something like:

```
error = np.zeros(y_test_predicted.shape)
```

before your loop would probably resolve it -- this pre-allocates an array which is the same shape as y_test_predicted.